# No Operator error code

Tags: c++

I am completing a hotel reservation form using C++ language. I keep getting no operator error for fin !=0. How can I address this error? Here is the actual coding...

```
void Hotel::show_room_record()
{
    cout << "R.Num" << setw(10) << "R.Stat" << setw(10) << "Category" << setw(10) << "Rent\n";
    ifstream fin("room.dat", ios::in);
    for (int p = 0; fin != 0; p = p + 15)
    {
        fin.seekg(p);
        fin >> room_no;
        fin >> room_status;
        fin >> category;
        fin >> rent;
        cout << room_no << setw(10) << room_status << setw(10) << category << setw(10) << rent << "\n";
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare `fin != 0`? What do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare fin with 0, fin wont return the next input.
First store the input in a variable, then compare it.

For your case, you probably want to check if the **next** character is a '0', or even a '\0'. 
Try using this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/

Your condition becomes (assuming you want '\0'):

```
fin.peek() != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test `fin != 0`. `fin` isn't a number, to testing for equality with 0 makes about as much sense as testing what kind of orange an apple is. You can test that `fin` is still readable though with a simple `fin` by taking advantage of [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), but that's tricky because the test for is readable will be made before reading. You can't test for failure before you have a chance to fail and that leaves open the possibility that the last reads failed and were not checked for validity.

Instead of trying to fix this, I'm going to [go all X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on you here and suggest something completely different.

Define a structure

```
struct room
{
    int room_no;
    string room_status;
    string category;
    int rent; // could be a float. Don't care much for this example
              // that said, watch out for rounding errors when dealing with floats  
};
```

Create a function that makes it really easy to read into this structure

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & in,
                          room & inroom)
{
    in >> inroom.room_no >> inroom.room_status >> inroom.category >> inroom.rent;
    return in;
}
```

Create a function that makes it really easy to write this structure

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                          const room & outroom)
{
    out << outroom.room_no << setw(10) << outroom.room_status << 
           setw(10) << outroom.category << setw(10) << outroom.rent;
    return out;
}
```

Make a `std::vector` of the above structure a member of the `Hotel` class

```
std::vector<room> rooms;
```

Read the file into it

```
room temp;
while (in >> temp)
{    
    rooms.push_back(temp);
}
```

Now the hotel knows the status of all the rooms without having to keep looking at the file. This makes printing easy.

```
for(room & r: rooms)
{
    cout << r << '\n';
}
```

It makes finding any room a simple traversal of rooms

```
for(room & r: rooms)
{
    if (r.whatever == desiredwhatever)
    {
        return r;
    }
}
```

and every now and then you rewrite the file if a room was changed.

```
std::ostream outfile("path to file goes here");
for(room & r: rooms)
{
    if (!(outfile << r << '\n'))
    {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

All of these things you probably have to do anyway. The only downside is if you are not allowed to use `std::vector`. In that case you either write a simple `vector` substitute or use an array and pray it never overflows.